# Submerging An Object From Ground

Tags: animation, particles

I'm trying to submerge a logo piece from out of ground. Image the earth cracks and soil particles move and logo itself slowly reveals under the soil.

I created a plane object, added soil texture and applied boolean operation to subtract the logo shape and I send the logo underneath the plane. Now, I want to cover the logo with particles and then I want to apply physics to particles so they move when logo moves up out of soil (plane object) - or maybe there is a better way to create this animation with geometry nodes.

I appreciate your answer and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There is more ways to achieve something like that. Usually Particle System is used. In some cases also cold smoke or fluid could work even better than particles because for something like sand or dust you would have to use a lot of particles ... it would be probably quite crazy to calculate :)*

---

### Particles

I didn't convert them to Rigid Body sim it would be more accurate, but a lot heavier to calculate. To let those here to collide with Colliders

- *Deflect* > enable **Size Deflect**

To Collide particles between each other

- *Force Field Settings* > enable **Self Effect** and under *Type1* > **Force** > *Strength* 1 (but animate the value from zero to one otherwise you get shock wave :). enable also *FallOff* > **Max Distance**  ... since my particle is *Size* 0.04 I set half *Max Distance* 0.02

[image]

- or switch *Physics* from *Newtonian* to **Fluid** and under Advanced set all to zero ... it seems to be more stable ... [more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2ywyKL0rNM)

[image]

Above the Cube I used subtle Turbulence Force Filed object to throw particles down.

### Smoke

For something more dusty ... Smoke simulation with *Domain* > **Heat -1**

[image]

### Fluid

Or you can try Fluid System and reuse Fluid Particles in some fake ... [for more see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjM16FUMOKM)

Comment: +1, but I don't think he really knows how to do it or else he would already have done it.

Comment: @vklidu Yes, definitely - I'm trying to do something like that. Would you care to upload a short tutorial if it is not much pain for you? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry ...sure, it wasn't meant o be answer. I wanted to be sure what OP is looking for.

Comment: People normally do that in the comments, but I guess this way is better (I personally agree, especially when you inderectly answer and then someone else thinks about it and answers instead of you;)